# Flutter and Firestore: debug usage

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to easily debug the read and write requests a Flutter app makes to Firestore? I'm getting a high number of reads, but battling to find where those are originating from in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the StackDriver logging User Interface?

It offers plenty of log analysis tools that you can use to monitor resources that are writing into your Firestore DataBase.

You can read more about this here [1].

Once you have created logs-based metrics, you can create charts and alerts on said metrics.

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs